# Finding a substring through a file of strings, c++

Tags: c++

beginner (mostly, anyway) here. I'm working on a program that takes words from a dictionary file, cycles it into a string, and then finds a specific substring that can possibly appear more than once per word. This program is looking through "Cie" and "Cei" to see how many times each pop up in the file. I've got it working for the most part, and it does accurately get the correct times for "cei". However, It's adding a couple extra increments to `tally` making it a tad off. Here's the code:

```
    struct Dictionary
{
    void checker(ifstream&);
    void out();
private:
    int tally, tally2 = 0;
};

void Dictionary::checker(ifstream&usa)
{
    string k;
    while (usa >> k)
    {
        transform(k.begin(), k.end(), k.begin(), ::tolower);
        string::size_type start_pos = 0;
        while(string::npos != (start_pos = k.find(cie, start_pos)))
        {
            tally++;
            ++start_pos;
        }
        string::size_type begin_pos = 0;
        while(string::npos != (begin_pos = k.find(cei, begin_pos)))
        {
            tally2++;
            ++begin_pos;
        }
    }
}



void Dictionary::out()
{
    cout << "The number of words cie is used in is: " << tally << endl;
    cout << "The number of words cei is used in is: " << tally2 << endl;
}


int main()
{
    try{
        //string american("/usr/share/dict/american");
        ifstream american {"./american.rtf"};
        if (!american)
            throw runtime_error("Can't open input file.");
        Dictionary words;
        words.checker(american);
        words.out();
    }
    catch(const runtime_error& e)
    {
        cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the content of the file? Without that, it's hard to tell. Also, which values is off? Try to reduce your example to just one of the two values if possible.

Comment: What is `cie` in the expression `k.find(cie, start_pos)`?

Comment: Is there a difference between `cie` and `cei`?  I highly recommend using verbose variable names.  Variable names have nothing to do with executable performance and are negligible to build time.

Comment: You are counting the number of occurrences, not the number of words.

Comment: Also, rtf??????